# Delete from three tables at once

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to write this query in one statement, but I don't really know how I can do it. I guess it is with joins.

```
START TRANSACTION;;

DELETE
FROM    user
WHERE   user_id= 1;

DELETE
FROM    issue
WHERE   user_id= 1;

DELETE
FROM    retour
WHERE   user_id= 1;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: The correct way would be to define a foreign key constraint with on delete cascade option.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have added relations in my database and what to do on delete/update (cascade). This works, thank you for your reply!